# Installing Comodo software on an Apache-based Modsecurity module

Tags: apache, vps, mod-security

I am very new to the VPS world and I want to install Modsecurity on my new VPS (Ubuntu 16, Apache, Webmin) after getting many recommendations to do so (already installed CSF-LFD but had many voices to install that one as well).

I searched for some documentation on how to integrate a Modsecurity-based rule software that is being automatically updated with any common system update, such as Comodo or Owasp. From what I understand, this should be rather a fast and easy process --- Creating a path reference to the Comodo program from within the Modsecurity conf file, yet most of the documentation I found, in various sites, seems to me as too long-for-no-good-reason, too vague, and undidactic.

I will thank an Apache experienced webmaster for a stepped explanation, dedicated for newbies and in the least amount of words possible, on how to do this integration, right after Modesecurity was installed and tested as working.

Comment: +1 for *undidactic*! I have no idea, however, this sounds like a good question. Too much documentation is poor at best and confusing as a result. Cheers!!

Comment: I assume you are not running a control panel of any kind and when you say mod_security is running and tested that you have also installed the appropriate agent, plugin and ruleset?

Comment: If by control panel you mean to a VHM, then I do use Webmin, otherwise I have no idea what kind of control panel you might mean to.

Comment: Agent? plugin? Will thank you for elaboration.

Comment: @Benia sorry for the delay. Control panel meaning, cPanel or Plesk.

Comment: Hi! Just updated the question --- I use Webmin as WHM.